# Bad Access exception in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, pointers, exc-bad-access, cocos2d-x

I am somewhat new to C++ programming and to Cocos2d-x and I am having some trouble with my first Cocos2d-x game. I am literally just trying to simulate gravity and update the player's position based on that. I am running Xcode 4.6.1 and for some reason I keep getting a BAD_ACCESS exception after one run (if I restart it seems to work). It happens at libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release. I have tried doing an allexceptions breakpoint and it breaks at a memory address in the dylib. This only happened after I added a velocity variable to my Player class, so maybe I am not properly allocating pointers and the such? Here are the relevant classes I believe.

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
class Player : public Sprite{
private:
    Point velocity;

public:
    static Player* create(const char *filename);
    void update(float delta);
    void setVelocity(const Point &v);
    const Point& getVelocity() const;
    ~Player();


};


#include "Player.h"
USING_NS_CC;
using namespace cocos2d;
Player::~Player(){

}

Player* Player::create(const char *filename){
    Player* self = (Player *) Sprite::create(filename);
    self->setVelocity(Point::ZERO);
    return self;
}

void Player::update(float delta){
    log("In player update");
    Point gravity = Point(0.0, -450.0);
    Point gravityStep = gravity * delta;
    this->setVelocity(this->getVelocity() + gravityStep);
    log("Velocity after setting: %f", getVelocity().y);
    Point stepVelocity = this->getVelocity() * delta;
    this->setPosition(this->getPosition() + stepVelocity);
    log("Position after setting: %f, %f", getPosition().x, getPosition().y);
}

void Player::setVelocity(const Point &v){
    this->velocity = v;
}

const Point& Player::getVelocity() const
{
    return this->velocity;
}

#include "GameLayer.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* GameLayer::scene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    Scene *scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    GameLayer *layer = GameLayer::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

GameLayer::~GameLayer(){
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(player);
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(map);
}

bool GameLayer::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    LayerColor *blueSky = LayerColor::create(*new Color4B(100, 100, 250, 255));
    this->addChild(blueSky);

    map = TMXTiledMap::create("level1.tmx");
    this->addChild(map);

    player = Player::create("koalio_stand.png");
    player->setPosition(Point(100,50));
    map->addChild(player, 15);

    setKeyboardEnabled(true);
    this->scheduleUpdate();

    return true;
}

void GameLayer::update(float dt){
    player->update(dt);
}
```

EDIT: So I figured out that the constructor of player was the problem. However, I'm wondering if it is kosher to do the following (since Player inherits from Sprite) to copy the Sprite function:

```
Sprite* Sprite::create(const char *filename)
{
    Sprite *sprite = new Sprite();
    if (sprite && sprite->initWithFile(filename))
    {
        sprite->autorelease();
        return sprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(sprite);
    return NULL;
}
```

and have the Player function be:

```
Player* Player::create(const char *filename){
    Player *sprite = new Player();
    if (sprite && sprite->initWithFile(filename))
    {
        sprite->setVelocity(Point::ZERO);
        sprite->autorelease();
        return sprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(sprite);
    return NULL;
}
```

Or perhaps is there a cleaner way to call the create of Sprite, but to create a Player object which inherits and sets the velocity?

Comment: I believe releasing `map` (which is a *terrible* name for a member variable in C++) in the `~GameLayer()` destructor after it is already added to the `layer` is not correct. The same for `player`. And I admit I don't program in cocos-x, but this just seems odd. I'm sure I'll be corrected if it is in-fact sop for cocos-x objects and their layers. They may be self-reference counted or some such.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip I wasn't so sure about those releases myself, but they don't seem to be changing the issue. I have actually narrowed it down to the line:     self->setVelocity(Point::ZERO); in the Player constructor but I'm not sure why this is causing the problem. Perhaps it is because I cast the Sprite create to a Player? Also, why is map such a bad name and what would be a better name? Thank you!

Comment: Its a bad name because when you say "map" in a C++ program people will naturally think of [`std::map<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Concerning the cast, does the creator `Sprite::create(const char *)` return anything besides `Sprite` instances ? If not, you're absolutely correct. That cast is bad-news. In C++ you want to avoid C-style casts anyway, generally using either `dynamic_cast<>` for polymorphic objects, or `static_cast<>`. `Player is *your* class, right? How does `Sprite::create()` know anything about it? (again, forgive my cocos-x naivety).

Comment: Okay, thanks that was the issue, I edited my questions because in terms of semantics I am wondering what is the better solution. Thanks

Comment: You have several options. You could template `Sprite::create` to make a derivation creator, and even SFINAE it to ensure you're using a derivation. Or a factory pattern. Anyway at least you recognize the issue, which is what is important.

Comment: have you tried by making your velocity as a public ???